# Why cant I get my sound to work on new Win7 installation?

Tags: windows-7, audio

Sound wont work after installing new windows.

I got a new HD and installed windows on it. I did the same thing on another hard drive and it worked fine. cant get sound to work with same hardware other than HD.

[image]

[image]

help. Speakers are selected in playback options. Speaker cord is fine, Computer reads it as plugged in on the realtek device manager. It is the correct cord, and the speakers are getting juice.

Motherboard is sabertooth x58 (integrated HD audio). I got the realtek drivers from the sabertooth driver site.

Also I checked in bios to make sure it was enabled already.

Answer (score 0):

Test: Control Panel - Hardware and Sound - Manage audio devices - Playback - Speakers are your "Default Device"